# Retrieve Firebase Data with ReactNative

Tags: firebase, react-native, listviewitem

I want to retrieve data from Firebase DB.

Here is the structure of the data:

```
words{
    word1{
        english:english
        french: french
    }
    word2{
        english:english
        french: french
    }
}
```

I want to display the french version in a ListView.

So far I have this :

```
     // Initialize Firebase
const firebaseConfig = {
     apiKey: "AIzaSyDWedZY1svNHxPUi2ReQJTlCf9Q60407E8",
    authDomain: "streetfrench-a84df.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://streetfrench-a84df.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "streetfrench-a84df",
    storageBucket: "streetfrench-a84df.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "551358813028"
};
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

class FirebaseReactNativeSample extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
      })
    };
    this.itemsRef = this.getRef().child('items');
  }

  getRef() {
    return firebaseApp.database().ref();
  }

  listenForItems(itemsRef) {
    itemsRef.on('value', (snap) => {

      // get children as an array
      var items = [];
      snap.forEach((child) => {
        items.push({
          french: child.val().french,
          english: child.val().english,
          _key: child.key
        });
      });

      this.setState({
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(items)
      });

    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.listenForItems(this.itemsRef);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <StatusBar title="Dictionary" />

        <ListView
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={this._renderItem.bind(this)}
          enableEmptySections={true}
          style={styles.listview}/>


          </View>
        )
      }
  _renderItem(item) {

    return (
      <ListItem item={item}/>
    );
  }

}

Expo.registerRootComponent(FirebaseReactNativeSample);
```

But nothing appears except the StatusBar. So can anyone provide me a guidance in order to correct this error?

Comment: Yes, should change `items` to `words`

Comment: Great, it works, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You aren't passing a reference path for firebase to fetch the data from. 
Ideally it should be

`firebaseApp.database().ref('/words/word1/')`. Also donot forget to check for the permissions that you have set in the db rules in the firebase db console.

read and write permissions must be set to `true` if you want all the users to access and edit the data.